# how to select order ID where all products quantity equal to zero?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the a table like below

[image]

I want to get recivedID that have `quant=0`

In this table we have tow recivedID them products quantity equal to zero
how to select recivedID which all it products quantity equal to zero 
i ho you understand what i mean , and i am very sorry for my bad english skill
Thank you

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        rd.recivedID FROM recivedDetailsTBL rd 
JOIN stockTBL s ON s.recivedID = rd.recivedID 
WHERE  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recivedDetailsTBL rd WHERE rd.recivedID =  @recivedID ) --3
        =
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stockTBL s WHERE s.quant =0 AND s.recivedID = @recivedID  )--3
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code at all to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT recivedID FROM stockTBL GROUP BY recivedID HAVING (SUM(quant) = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're talking about something similar to this in SQL Format:

```
SELECT recivedID FROM stock WHERE quant = '0'
```

Such a query would select the recivedID from the Stock Table where the quant of the item is 0.

Comment: Maybe not all product in this order equal to zero

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong it'll still find items that are an INT, or at least thats how I've seen it work so far. 

The way you worded your questions Amal sounds like you only want to find the products received with quant of 0 though. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

OK,

So where respondents are getting confused is your explanation...

From your explanation, you can have many `prodID` in one `recivedID`

From what you have been saying, you only want the `recivedID` where the sum of the `quant` is 0.

So you need to use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
recivedID
FROM recivedDetailsTBL
GROUP BY recivedID
HAVING SUM(quant) = 0
```

Comment: you are right 
thank you 
and i am sorry for my bad  explanation

Answer (score 0):

**First:-**

use the next code:-

```
Select  recivedID
From  TableName
GROUP BY recivedID
HAVING SUM(quant) = 0
```

**Second:-**

Lean SQL Statements Concepts, there are thousands of resourses,
use this as an example:

[SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: no you dont understand what i mean
maybe one product quantity only equal to zero then this statement will return recivedID
what i need is return recivedID when all product in that recived equal to zero

Comment: @AmalAhmed  So, Get the updated query, Hope it what you need.